# Looking for the name of the property used to solve this question: In a lattice if $a≤b≤c$, show that (i)$a⊕b=b*c$ (ii)$(a*b)⊕(b*c)=(a⊕b)*(a⊕c)=b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I've been trying to solve this question

> In a lattice if $a≤b≤c$, show that (i)$a⊕b=b*c$ (ii)$(a*b)⊕(b*c)=(a⊕b)*(a⊕c)=b$

for a while now but I simply can't find anything even remotely related to this question. I've asked a couple of my friends about this as well and they say this is a theorem but can't remember its name. I don't want the direct answer (which, by the way is fine), just the name of the theorem if possible.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the math thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, how does that ?

Comment: You have a tuto and reference  here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation. I assume $\oplus$ is the join and $\ast$ is the meet?

Comment: If yes, then these both follow immediately from the fact that $x \leq y \iff x * y = x \iff x \oplus y = y$. I don't know of a name for this theorem - in my mind it is the _definition_ of the order in terms of the lattice operations.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor In Introduction to lattices and order, by Davey and Priestley, the property  you referred to is called *The Connecting Lemma* (Lemma 2.8, in the 2nd edition).

Comment: @amrsa: Thanks for the reference! It's useful to have names for things, for exactly situations like this ^_^

Comment: @amrsa I think that might be the one, I will check it out. Thanks!